# Why is the wrapper div getting the top margin applied when applying to its child div?

Tags: css, layout, html, margin

Here is an example html:

```
<div id = "wrapper">
   <div id = "content">
   </div>
</div>
```

here is the CSS:

```
#wrapper
{
  width:  1000px;
  min-height:  850px;
  border:   1px solid;
}
    #content
    {
        height:  450px;
        float:   left;
        margin:  50px 0px 0px 0px;
    }
```

So when you look in the browser, the wrapper div is getting the margin applied to it?  why is that?

Comment: it doesnt for me (chrome 10).

Comment: No it's not: http://jsfiddle.net/DSyRA/

Comment: What browser are you seeing this problem in?

Comment: All I see is the Body's default 8px margin and 10px padding. FF4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you removed the margin in the body tag?

```
<body  marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">
```